# How to pass extra value(object) by navController

Tags: android, kotlin

I use a API to get some values and the values recived are in the type of

```
object Fridge {
    data class fridge(
    val number: Int,
    val offset: Int,
    val results: List<Result>,
    val totalResults: Int
)

data class Result(....
```

After getting the values I want to move to a different fragment and then set the values in that fragment

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fridge_to_fridgeDishViewFragment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send it through bundle as following way.
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fridge_to_fridgeDishViewFragment, Bundle())